# Create multiple zips using maven

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I have multi module Project and each module has different configuration folders. Now I want to create zip files based configuration folder using maven and assembly.

```
Project
   |
   ---module 1
   |   |
   |    ---dir 1
   |   |
   |    ---dir 2
   |   |
   |    ---dir3 
   |   |
   |    ---src
   |
   ---module 2
       |
        ---dir 1
       |
        ---dir 2 
       |
        ---src
```

My requirement is to create zip files based on directory names. Project has more than 50 modules and each module has different directory names.

Please suggest.

adding child pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>iterator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>collective-package</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <items>
                            <item>dir 1</item>
                            <item>dir 2</item>
                            <item>dir 3</item>
                        </items>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <testSourceDirectory>test-integration-src</testSourceDirectory>
</build>
```

parent pom.xml

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>iterator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>collective-package</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>iterator</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <pluginExecutors>
                                <pluginExecutor>
                                    <plugin>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <version>3.1.0</version>
                                    </plugin>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <descriptors>
                                            <descriptor>assembly/zip_assembly.xml</descriptor>
                                        </descriptors>
                                        <finalName>@item@</finalName>

                                    </configuration>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </pluginExecutor>
                            </pluginExecutors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

zip_assembly.xml

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
<id>${project.version}</id>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
</formats>
<moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
        <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
        <includes>
            <include>com.test:*</include>
        </includes>
        <sources>
            <excludeSubModuleDirectories>false</excludeSubModuleDirectories>
            <fileSets>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>${project.basedir}/target/classes</directory>
                    <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>com</exclude>
                        <exclude>schema</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </fileSet>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>${project.basedir}/../modulex/conf</directory>
                    <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileSet>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>${project.basedir}/../modulex/scripts</directory>
                    <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*.sh</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileSet>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>${project.basedir}/conf/<need here @item@></directory> <!--need directory name from parent/child pom.xml . sothat it picks the files from dir x-->
                    <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileSet>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>${project.basedir}/../core/scripts</directory>
                    <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*.sh</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileSet>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
                    <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*.jar</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>*-tests.jar</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </fileSet>
             </fileSets>
        </sources>
    </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>
```

I can create zip for each directory but can't include files under dir x into zip. because I cant get dir name at runtime in zip_assembly.xml

how can we pass value of @item@ to zip_assembly.xml files

Comment: The first question is: Why have all modules different configuration folder and for what purpose? Are those modules jar/ear/ejb/wars?

Comment: only one source folder(which is not mentioned above. Each module has once src folder parallel to dir folders) and different config files which contains the config details(Mq details and other). we use each directory as a different adapter.

Comment: The convention is to have things like that into `src/main/resources` and this will be packaged into the resulting jar file? The question about what kind of artifact you produce has not been answered? Can you elaborate more detail cause I don't understand that you use a directory as a different adapter ?

Comment: artifect is jar which doesn't contains resources(contains only .class files).  We can say adapter means interface  between 2 systems based on its config files.

Comment: @khmarbaise added more details above. zip files should create based on each dir. Each zip should contains the jar and files from respected directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution. Used maven-antrun-plugin instead of maven-assembly-plugin